# How to iterate over variables in an ansible dictionary

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a role that should scatter NGINX configs across different servers using Jinja2 templates, referring to the variables specified in *defaults/main*, please tell me how to write a loop to iterate over these variables correctly, tried it through with_items and with_nested, but nothing happens.
The *defaults/main* file looks like this:

```yaml
allservers:
  server1:
    - { src: 'templates/sites-enabled/api.j2',                       dest: '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/api.conf' }                               
    - { src: 'templates/sites-enabled/citizens.j2',                  dest: '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/citizens.conf' }
    - { src: 'templates/sites-enabled/control.j2',                   dest: '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/control.conf' }
    - { src: 'templates/sites-enabled/documents.j2',                 dest: '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/documents.conf' }
    - { src: 'templates/sites-enabled/orders.j2',                    dest: '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/orders.conf' }
    - { src: 'templates/sites-enabled/logs.j2',                      dest: '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/logs.conf' }

  server2:
    - { src: 'templates/sites-enabled/permissions.j2',               dest: '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/permissions.conf' }
    - { src: 'templates/sites-enabled/documents.j2',                 dest: '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/documents.conf' }
    - { src: 'templates/sites-enabled/default.j2',                   dest: '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default' }
    - { src: 'templates/sites-enabled/orders.j2',                    dest: '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/orders.conf' }
    - { src: 'templates/sites-enabled/settings.j2',                  dest: '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/settings.conf' }
```

Comment: Does `allservers` have sub-dicts `server1` and `server2`? Also, please update the question on what is your expected result/behaviour after looping with these variables?

Comment: Yes, there are many sub-variable servers 1,2,3, etc., the task is to transfer conf files to the corresponding servers.

Comment: This seems to me like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you seems to have here are variables that should be defined on hosts level, in an inventory, and then 'simply' looped on. As @seshadri_c was advising please explain your use case in more depth by [edit]'ing your question.

Comment: Also, a good advise would be to not mix the JSON and YAML syntax as you are doing it here.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε That is not JSON syntax, JSON requires double-quoting keys. This is simply YAML flow syntax, which does not have obvious downsides and therefore there is no need to advise against it.

Comment: @flyx my bad, JSON-like syntax. Still, the pure YAML counterpart of that syntax would be way more readable, and won't for the OP to `\t` the `dest` key to have them aligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you do not want to change your data structure, and that `server1` and `server2` refer to hosts in your inventory.

```
---                                                                             
- hosts: server1:server2                                                        
  remote_user: ansible                                                          
  vars:                                                                         
    allservers:                                                                 
      server1:                                                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file1", dest: "/tmp"}                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file2", dest: "/tmp"}                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file3", dest: "/tmp"}                                  
      server2:                                                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file4", dest: "/tmp"}                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file5", dest: "/tmp"}                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file6", dest: "/tmp"}    


  tasks:
    - name: Copy template
      template:
        src: "{{ item.src }}"
        dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in allservers.keys()
      with_items:
        - "{{ allservers[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

Another solutions is to include a task (`copy_template.yml`) which you will iterate over using `with_dict: allservers`.

*playbook.yml*

```
---                                                                             
- hosts: server1:server2                                                        
  remote_user: ansible                                                          
  vars:                                                                         
    allservers:                                                                 
      server1:                                                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file1", dest: "/tmp"}                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file2", dest: "/tmp"}                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file3", dest: "/tmp"}                                  
      server2:                                                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file4", dest: "/tmp"}                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file5", dest: "/tmp"}                                  
          - { src: "/tmp/file6", dest: "/tmp"}                                  
  tasks:                                                                        
    - include: copy_template.yml                                                
      vars:                                                                     
        server: "{{ item.key }}"                                                
      with_dict:                                                                
        - "{{ allservers }}"
```

*copy_template.yml*

```
---                                                                             
- debug:                                                                        
    msg: "{{ template.src }}  and  {{ template.dest }}"                         
  loop: "{{ allservers[server] }}"                                  
  when: server == inventory_hostname                                            
  loop_control:                                                                 
    loop_var: template
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I need!